# Apache Beam/Dataflow: Best way to initialize state per deployment

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Beam/Dataflow streaming pipeline. I need to update metadata to the element being processed every time Beam topology is restarted/re-launched so I can identify topology version for each elements. For example, say I can insert topology start time as a metadata, but want to do this in a way such that doesn't require me to pass in date as a job launching argument.

Having a statefulDoFn may help in this situation, however is there a native support for this type of behavior?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: (1) You are running a streaming pipeline. (2) You want to track a kind of offset over updates of this streaming pipeline. Is this correct? If so, this is very similar to tracking offsets when reading from Kafka - and you're right that stateful dofn would do the trick for you.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you want to track state across multiple runs of a batch pipeline - well, that's not supported natively by Beam/DAtaflow. Instead, you would need to pass a date pipeline argument, or keep the metadata stored in a persistent database.

Comment: @Pablo Is there a way to get timestamp for which window was first initialized?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I am interested in identifying time for which Beam topology initialized the window for the first time (which means when we started the topology for the first time) via context which is available in DoFn. Use case is to version logic which is processing each message in a way that we won't have to pass in external value when launching the job. Ex. say I have topology x, I start x, get topology start timestamp and add to each message. I shutdown x and re-launch x, I should get new topology start timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Check the @Setup and @Teardown annotations of DoFn.